# SQL Server Report builder Using Lookup and Exclude blank and null

Tags: reporting-services

I'm driving myself crazy yet again. :)  I'm using SQL Server Report Builder.  I have two datasets where I use one of them as a lookup.  The lookup works fine, but it also shows blank and null dates.  I only want the report to show if there is a date, not the blanks.

This is my lookup

```
=Lookup(Fields!Inmate_ID.Value,Fields!InmateID.Value,Fields!Recorded_Date.Value,"ChronicClinic"))
```

I feel like I've tried everything under the sun, but I can't seem to get the report to NOT show blanks/nulls in the Recorded_Date column. I don't need the rows that contain the blanks/nulls. It seems like it being a date field throws a whammy into it.

Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you,
Tara

The lookup is fine and returns one value.  I'm using Inmate_ID and InmateID in my lookup.  The Expression is

```
=Lookup(Fields!Inmate_ID.Value,Fields!InmateID.Value,Fields!Recorded_Date.Value,"ChronicClinic")
```

It won't let me paste a picture.  I don't want the row to show if there is NOT a date present.  I do want to see if if there is a date. I don't want to see the 2nd row. There is no date.  Example below:

```
Inmate ID   First Name      Last Name       Date of Confinement Status  Recorded Date   
152350      Name Removed    Name Removed    3/10/2020           Active  10/21/2020  
152433      Name Removed    Name Removed    8/4/2019            Active
```

Thanks again!

Comment: can you show what you mean by " but it also shows blank and null dates"? is the recorded_date column the one you are doing the lookup on? can you not set the property to show "" if the value of that report item is blank?

Comment: As far as your Lookup goes, the only way to that you would be getting NULLs is if you have multiple records for each Inmate ID and some are blank. If you do have multiples, you'd probably want the MAX and need to do something more complicated like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142562/ssrs-max-date-from-lookupset

Comment: I edited the original post with some clarification.  Thanks so much for taking the time to help.  I've spent hours trying this and that.

Comment: Will you ever get a situation where you have `InmateID`s in your 'lookup' dataset that are not in the main dataset. If not then you could make the second dataset the primary one. If you need more help then posting a sample of data from each dataset will help us to recreate your problem. The other obvious question is "Is there a reason that you you cannot do this in your dataset query?" It would be really simple doing this in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this does not help, please see my comment above.

Select the entire row using the row header handle, right-click and choose row visibilty.

Select "Show or hide based on an expression" then set the expression to something like

```
=Lookup(Fields!Inmate_ID.Value,Fields!InmateID.Value,Fields!Recorded_Date.Value,"ChronicClinic")) = Nothing
```

This will evaluate your lookup and if it equals `Nothing` (no lookup found) then will return `True` as the `Hidden` property *(The Row visibility settings are actually setting a property called `Hidden` which is a little confusing..)*

Comment: That worked!  I had been trying the "show or hide based on an expression", but didn't try it with =nothing.  I also did try doing it through the query, but kept getting an error on everything I tried.  Thanks so very much!!

Comment: No problem , can you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark under the voting buttons to theleft ofthe question). Thanks